# Need to fetch data between two date range with dummy rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a requirement where I need to fetch data between two dates from the database. On top of that I am having a case where I say need data for last 24 hours, so the data returned on above query should give data hour specific. So, let say if time slot is 1:00 AM to 2:00 AM and there are 2 rows residing in this time slot it should return value as 2 and so on count for each time slot.

Suggest something on this problem.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Basically I need to write store procedure for this, so for now I have data (all rows) between two dates (date range). I am looking forward for help where I can have logic in place in query itself to minimize manipulations at application level.

Answer (score -1):

CASE 1 :    select count(rows) from yourtable where dates between 'date one' and 'date two';

CASE 2 :    select extract(date from datecolumn), extract(hour from datecolumn, count(rows) from

yourtable where date between 'today's date' and 'yesterday's date'

group by extract(date from datecolumn), extract(hour from datecolumn)

order by extract(date from datecolumn), extract(hour from datecolumn)